# Find the pdf of $X+Y$ (discrete case)

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Given the marginal pdfs:

$$p_X(k)= e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\text{ and }p_Y(k)= e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^k}{k!},\quad k=0,1,2,\ldots$$

find the pdf of $X+Y$.

I know for $W=X+Y$, $p_W(w)= \sum_x p_X(x)p_Y(w-x)$

So far I have:

$$p_W(w)= e^{-\lambda-\mu}\sum_x\frac{\lambda^x\mu^{w-x}}{x!(w-x)!}
,\ldots$$

but I am not seeing where this is coming from. If you're summing all $x$'s, wouldn't you get an infinite sum?

Comment: As is all too often the case, it has not been mentioned that we are to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The formula is correct if and only if they are independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
e^{-\lambda-\mu}\sum_x\frac{\lambda^x\mu^{w-x}}{x!(w-x)!}&=e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\sum_x\frac{w!}{x!(w-x)!}\frac{\lambda^x\mu^{w-x}}{w!}=\\
 &=e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\sum_x\dbinom{w}{x}\frac{\lambda^x\mu^{w-x}}{w!}=\\
 &=\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{w!}\sum_x\dbinom{w}{x}\lambda^x\mu^{w-x} \\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=}e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\frac{(\lambda+\mu)^w}{w!}
\end{align*}
where $(*)$ holds by Newton binomial theorem.